# Single authentication for 2 ASP web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing ASP webforms application, which uses SQL membership for authentication. Now I want to create a separate ASP MVC application, which will be linked from the navigation menu of the original web forms application.

I want the new MVC application to "share" the authentication with the older application, so that the user does not have to login again. I think that the new application cannot read the authentication cookie of the other application.
So is there any way I can use the same login for 2 applications?

Thanks,